# Which word will fit here?

Tags: single-word-requests

> "Our *allies* arrived but not until later. They had waited to see which
>   way the war would turn. Only in the end did they choose to cast their
>   lot in with us", the baron said.
>
> "A decisive choice nonetheless", Victor said _____________. "For it
>   was what helped us snatch the victory."

I am trying to make Victor sound fair and impartial. He is trying to point out that the outcome was favourable despite the initial hiccup. However, I am not sure which word would fill that space.

Comment: You say you are 'trying to make Victor sound fair and impartial', but have him saying X was what helped  him(them) win. Not sure what your are asking for.

Comment: @lbf: Victor is trying to answer in  a way such that he does not appear to be taking anyone's side. He understands the baron is angry but also understands why the allies took their time to make the decision. In the end, what matters to him is the outcome which came about. Hope this helps.

Comment: he says:  "For it was what helped us snatch the victory." That is not an impartial statement.

Comment: He is just stating the facts  as he sees it, to corroborate his earlier statement. I, honestly fail to see why it does not come across as an impartial statement. If you, however, feel it does not go with that general feeling, please feel free to modify it (or remove it) to make it seem impartial.

Comment: @KJO: ahh...ok...makes sense now...I agree with the alteration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A word like *[equably](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/equable?q=equably#equable__3)* would work.

> **equable**, *adj*.: calm, reasonable, and not easily made angry or upset [MacMillan]

So your example becomes:

> "A decisive choice nonetheless," Victor said equably.